# plot a 3D graph using points in matlab

Tags: matlab, surf, plot3d

I am struggling to create a 3D graph using data comming from an array. for example

```matlab
x = [ 12 23 43 89 56 23 15 78 89 56 20 8]
y = [ 120 56 69 89 56 15 65 89 70 69 27 10]
z = [ 89 56 43 89 56 23 15 63 23 78 36 9]
```

this is sample set of points I already succeeded to plot those points.
now am trying to join them together to form a surface.

what am trying to plot.
[image]

this is what i have

[image]

Comment: For a surface, you need a mesh of `x,y,z` points, not a list. Yours looks like a 3D line plot from the data, rather than a surface. Maybe you can interpolate a mesh using `griddata`